# Handling of two objects at same time

Tags: java

I have two objects A & B(which are interrelated)
First A is inserted in DB and we get an output result. The result contains a ID which will be then set in Object B and then it will be passed to DB.

This is the simple scenario which we can do by getter and setter. But the problem is that if there are five objects of A type and corresponding five objects of B type. So how we can manage them by using java programming.

A1 is related to B1 similarly A2-> B2 and so on.

And we get an array of Object A and array of object B at same time. How we can combine the objects in java so that there is no confusion such that when we save A2 in DB and the generated ID is being set in B3, which is actually supposed to be set in B2.

Comment: Have you got any code to illustrate your problem?

Comment: Are you using any kind of ORM framework, like Hibernate? Do you do simple JDBC access? Please provide more details. Also, did you try anything so far? If positive, please post relevant snippets of code that doesn't work or you think might work.

Comment: When you are reading id of saved A object and setting in B object and so on..your code will take care of multiple objects like that..assuming you are doing it in loop...Where is the confusion..

Answer (score 0):

What i can figure out from the scenario, for entity A and B is :

> A 'has ' B (one to one relation)

ORMs like hibernate is the solution for your queries (involves learning curve), other wise you need to handle it manually. 
Looking forward to see if there are any other options available.

Comment: We are not using the ORM. We have to handle using simple java logic.